# Showing character n for new line in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am implementing an application which has a feature of creating and posting message using http post. What I am doing is , I am getting text from edittext and adding it to NameValuepair and attaching this to the post url. My problem is after posting the message, in the message it is showing 'n' wherever I have used newline. I mean while entering message, wherever I pressed Enter button there it is showing 'n', while typing I am able to put newline, but after posting 
it is showing only 'n' and the whole body in single line only. Here is the code.

```
etMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMessageCreate);     
etMessage.setSingleLine(false);
etMessage.setInputType(etMessage.getInputType()|EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(10);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",etMessage.getText().toString()));
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

And here is the xml.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_light_frame"
    android:id="@+id/etMessageCreate"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/etSubject"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not showing \n instead? This would be the replacement for a newline!

Comment: it is showing only n....

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your xml layout file:
`android:singleLine = "false"

   android:inputType="textMultiLine"` 
I used this and it worked fine ;) 
hope this helps.

EDIT:
ok, i didn't notice, that you're setting singleLine to false programatically. :) So try to add textMultiLine to "inputType"

:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

Comment: only one parameter is allowed in setEntity().

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. encoding param goes to constructor of `UrlEncodedFormEntity`